# Database did not create with annotation on entity class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I created my entity classes and annotations normally, but hibernate can not generate the tables in my database.

```
##DataSource settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@//localhost:1521/BD_GESTION_OPERATION?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&userSSL=false&useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=system
spring.datasource.password=SeCret
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

##Disabling spring basic security
security.basic.enabled=false

##Start up port
server.port=8082

##Specify DBMS
spring.jpa.database=ORACLE

##Show/Hide SQL queries
spring.jpa.show-sql=false

##Hibernate DDL Auto (create, create-drop, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

##Naming strategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy

##Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

Comment: Hibernate doesn't create tables for you, you have to provide an existing database structure.

Comment: You don't tell it to create the database. You probably want `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create`. Refer to section 10.2 of https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-database-initialization

Comment: Is your entity properly discovered?

Answer (score 0):

Delete old tables. In your `application.properties`, set property like that (this is default, even you no need declaring it)

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
```

You also want to try

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

Reference https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-hibernate